# Add conditional array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array definition

```
var array = [
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three",
]
```

...but I only want "three" to be added when another variable is true.

```
var array = [
  "One",
  "Two",
  (addThree ? "Three" : undefined),
]
```

The issue is, if addThree is false, then the array becomes ["One","Two",undefined] when I just want it to be ["One","Two"].

Comment: Very, very bad, but: `...(addThree ? ['Three'] : [])`

Comment: @Li357 What's so bad about that?

Comment: It's terribly unreadable IMO

Comment: If I didn't want to support IE11, I'd definitely go with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of ways to do this.

**1.** Using `spread operator (...)`

```js
var addThree=false;
const array = [
  "One",
  "Two",
  ...(addThree ? ['Three'] : []),
]
console.log(array);
```

> **spread operator (...)** for Array literals does nothing if its operand is an empty Array.**Using the spread operator in this manner leads to slightly cryptic code.**

**2.** Another Alternative is to conditionally insert either elements or undefineds and to then filter the latter values out

```js
var addThree=true;


var array = [
 "One",
  "Two",
  (addThree ? 'Three' : undefined)
].filter(Boolean);
console.log(array);
```

**3.** An elegant and self-descriptive solution is to use push() to construct the Array:

```js
var addThree=true;
const array = [];
array.push('One');
array.push('Two');
if (addThree) {
        array.push('Three');
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: I ended up using filter - spread syntax is gorgeous but not IE-friendly, and the push method is a little too clunky

Comment: @snazzybouche Don't forget, there's always pre-processors like babel which will compile your script into more user-friendly forms for all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

You could take [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for checking `addThree` and take the value or an empty array.

The empty array does not change the length of the returned array.

```js
var addThree = false,
    array = ["One", "Two"].concat(addThree ? "Three" : []);
    
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize it with static items that aren't going to change, and then conditionally add the third if your condition is true:

```
var array = [
  "One",
  "Two",
];

if (addThree) {
   array.push("Three");
}
```